# How to install a program developed in J2ME (JavaME) in a BlackBerry WITHOUT re-booting?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I have a very **unreasonable** requirement from my overlord.

I developed a little application in **JavaME**. It is OK.

He is testing the app in different models of the BlackBerry. In some models, after the installation of the **.jad**, the phone ask for re-boot, in others, you could use the app just after the installation.

As a new requirement the app must be functional **without** re-booting.

Could you tell me how to do this? and with which code of **JavaME**? Have not found any relevant information (**in code**) about it.

Notice that the app is developed with Java and **NOT** with the **BB SDK**. Even more, I don't know the architecture of the BB's to see why in some cases it needs re-booting (neither the architecture of the other mobiles that work with **JavaME**!!).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the application has not been installed on a device previously (or the device has been rebooted after the application has been removed) then you should not have to reboot after installation. There are a number of reasons why removal or replacement of (upgrading) an application will require a reboot. They all boil down to the OS has only one instance of the JVM and it is still holding references to objects that are defined in the application.

A very simple application that has not run since the last garbage collection may be replaced without rebooting. Any application that registers a listener or other objects with the the OS, or runs in the background will usually require a reboot.

To test what a new customer would experience having never used your application before try this:

1. If the application is installed on the device, remove it.
2. If the device does not reboot, reboot it (Alt-Caps-Del or battery pull).
3. Once it has finished restarting install the application.

Comment: Thank you!. It is possible to do point (1) with code? Remember that I'm not using the **BB SDK**. **EDIT**: the re-booting behavior would be present even when updating the app?

Comment: When updating a reboot is a possibility, depending on the program, and the state of the JVM. Is there no way to convince your overlord that a blackberry rebooting after an application install is routine? There may be some things you could do if you wrote a program using the BB SDK to install your J2ME application that would avoid rebooting, but that other program would probably be more complex than application your currently developing.

Comment: I see. Definitively, I'll talk to my overlord about this (hoping that he will be reasonable). Thank you!